# How do you make a UITableViewDatasource independant of the UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In the past, I have always registered the class and the reuse id for a cell in the "viewDidLoad" method of the view controller.  That works fine when the view controller conforms to the UITableViewDataSource and acts as the data source of the table.  However, I want to make an independent class that acts as a datasource.

In other words, calling "registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:" or "registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:" in "viewDidLoad" creates a very tight binding between the view controller and the class that is acting as the data source and violates the encapsulation of the data source implementation: specifically, the data source must use the same class and reuse id as specified in the view controller when implementing "cellForRowAtIndexPath:".

Is there any method where the data source can specify the class and reuse ID, and keep it's internal implementation details hidden from the view controller?

Comment: Can you make the reuse identifier a property of your `UIViewDataSource` and then set the property from your view controller?

Comment: That is half of it.  I am doing that as a work around.  I guess you could also specify the class or the nib as well, but then you are REALLY exposing implementation detail!  But I really want to be able to change the data source class without having to change other classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `dataSource`/`delegate` have some method that configures a table view to its liking.

For example, in your data source object:

```
- (void)configureTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView registerClass:[SomeClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
}
```

Alternatively, but slightly more awkward (IMO), would be to register it when you get a call for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (before you actually dequeue). You should ensure that you only register it once per table view.

Comment: The data source is able to configure the table, but WHEN to do it is the problem.  Your alternative idea is workable, though.  Yes, it means that you have to track state, but it is internal to the class.  If I decide that I want to use a different cell class, I will be able to do so without having any changes outside of the data source.  I am going to try it.

Comment: I just tried it and it works fine.  I added a simple state boolean inside the class.  It could be generalized to work with multiple UITableViews by tracking the state of each one.  Yes, it is awkward, but it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The custom class that acts as the data source *must* conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, but there's nothing that prevents it from conforming to additional protocols that you define.  For example, you could define a protocol with a method that takes a nib name and a cell ID as inputs, and is expected to register that NIB when called.

Alternatively, the designated initializer for the custom class could be `initWithNibName:andCellID:`.  When you alloc/init the custom class, pass the nib name and cell ID, and let the custom class register the NIB.

Comment: Providing an additional interface would work, but again it would put the implementation detail into the interface.